# Configure clojure http-kit to use a forward proxy

Tags: clojure, proxy, http-kit

I have a little Clojure app that uses http-kit to send some http post requests to a server. I want to route the https POST request through a proxy P, ie. I want the traffic to go like App->Proxy->Server.

(This is because the target host X restricts access based on IP)

Is this possible?

Also the App runs on an ubuntu server, are there maybe system-level configurations possible to make http-kit use a proxy server? I prefer other processes to be unaffected though.

Answer (score 3):

http-kit is supposed to follow the standard method of configuring proxies in Java:

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostURL \
-Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber \
-Dhttp.proxyUser=someUserName \
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=somePassword
```

which you can set in your lein profile or in the application server if you are using one.

Comment: i added this to my project.clj :jvm-opts ["-Dhttp.proxyHost=someip"  "-Dhttp.proxyPort=3128"] but it didn't work. is there a way to verify these settings are actually used? I run this from the repl, would that matter?

Answer (score 1):

http-clj now support proxy: https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#proxies

For http-kit, according to the [author's reply in this issue](https://github.com/http-kit/http-kit/issues/75#issuecomment-22771808), the answer is NO.

But the good news is fewer weeks before it support basic HTTP proxy ( commit a207537 on http-kit ).

After all, it seems there is no way to set up a system wide proxy for JVM applications.